# Insert Array values insert to single ID into mysql database using php and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax

Insert multi product into single id using array insertions with Ajax load. Maybe use Explode but need a clear instruction for this type of output:
[image]

all product (problem) will input into one single id. Those problem list are added by Ajax.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    try {
    $serviceTitle = $_POST['serviceTitle'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];

    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dacca'); 
    $time = date('h:i:s');
    $createBy = $_SESSION['sess_username'];

    $_SESSION['orderNo'] = $_POST['orderNo'];
    $_SESSION['customerNo'] = $_POST['customerNo'];

    if($_POST['Submit']==='Submit'){
        for($i=0;$i<count($serviceTitle);$i++){
            $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO invoice (orderNo,customerNo,productName,price,quantity,amount,createDate,createTime,createBy) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $statement->execute(array($_POST['orderNo'],$_POST['customerNo'],$serviceTitle[$i],$price[$i],$quantity[$i],$amount[$i],$date,$time,$createBy));
        }
    }
    header("location: order_confirm_tech_step2.php");
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
            $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

It will insert at same orderNo and customerNo but I want to insert data row like this:
[image]
thanks in advance.

Comment: Completely irrelevant to the question, but I thought to point out that the generally accepted shorthand version of "quantity" should be "Qty", not "Qnt"

Answer (score 0):

Hi the best way I think is to give different name for all inpunt like `'new_screen_price' 'old_screen_price'`

if your form is generate by js you can do this if isn't put direct in html you have

```
<input name='new_screen_price'>
<input name='new_screen_qty'>
...
```

after you take your single value in php like

```
$newScreen = [];
$newScreen['name'] = 'new screen';
$newScreen['price'] = $_POST['new_screen_price'];
```

put yours array product in one

```
$products = [];
$products['newScreen'] = $newScreen;
```

you are ready for you request i just do for two params price and name but oviously you need for all

```
foreach($products as $prod){
   $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO invoice (orderNo,customerNo,productName,price,quantity,amount,createDate,createTime,createBy) VALUES (?,?,:name,:price,...)");
   $statement->bindParam(':name', $prod->name);
   $statement->bindParam(':price', $prod->price);
   $statement->execute();
}
```

good day i hope this can help you

Comment: Well, How declare value of "orderNo,customerNo,createDate,createTime,createBy" ?