# for loop convert to foreach loop with PDO in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, pdo, foreach

Convert to "foreach loop" from "for loop" where using array and counting array positon with $serviceTitle after data will insert into MySQl

```
for($i=0;$i<count($serviceTitle);$i++){        
    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO invoice (orderNo,customerNo,productName,
                 price,quantity,amount,createDate,createTime,
                 createBy) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");        
    $statement->execute(array($orderNo,$customerNo,$serviceTitle[$i],$price[$i],$quantity[$i],$amount[$i],$date,$time,$createBy));
 }
```

Before answer the question check this question : [Insert Array values insert to single ID into mysql database using php and PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816178/array-values-insert-to-single-id-into-mysql-database-using-php)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should `prepare` your statement only one time before the loop and then just use it via `execute` all time.

Comment: @Amranur: why? And what is "$serviceTitle"? How/why would it provide the array position?

Comment: $serviceTitle use for array input from form input (<input type="checkbox"  name="serviceTitle[]" value="<?php echo $row['serviceTitle']; ?>">) as $serviceTitle = $_POST['serviceTitle'].

Comment: please check this question before answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816178/array-values-insert-to-single-id-into-mysql-database-using-php

thanks

Comment: Where are `$orderNo,$customerNo,$price[$i],$quantity[$i],$amount[$i],$date,$time,$createBy` defined? Perhaps if you shared the contents of `$serviceTitle` it might help?

Comment: Can you post a var_dump( $_POST )?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {

        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dacca');

        /* check that all variables exist in the POST array */
        if( isset( $_POST['Submit'], $_POST['serviceTitle'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['quantity'], $_POST['amount'], $_POST['orderNo'], $_POST['customerNo'] ) ){

            /*
                Assuming that the fields serviceTitle,price,quantity and amount
                are named like field[] in the form then their values will be 
                arrays in the POST array
            */
            $serviceTitle = $_POST['serviceTitle'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];
            $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
            $amount = $_POST['amount'];
            $orderNo = $_POST['orderNo'];
            $customerNo = $_POST['customerNo'];


            $date = date('Y-m-d');
            $time = date('h:i:s');
            $createBy = $_SESSION['sess_username'];




            /* check that key variables are arrays as you intend to access as arrays below */
            if( is_array( $serviceTitle ) && is_array( $price ) && is_array( $quantity ) && is_array( $amount ) ){

                /* prepare the sql statement */
                $sql='insert into `invoice` ( `orderno`, `customerno`, `productname`, `price`, `quantity`, `amount`, `createdate`, `createtime`, `createby` ) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
                $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

                if( $stmt ){
                    foreach( $serviceTitle as $i => $arr ){
                        try{
                            $args=array(
                                $orderNo,
                                $customerNo,
                                $arr[$i],
                                $price[$i],
                                $quantity[$i],
                                $amount[$i],
                                $date,
                                $time,
                                $createBy
                            );
                            $stmt->execute( $args );
                        }catch( PDOException $e ){
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }

                    $stmt->close();
                    $db->close();

                    $_SESSION['orderNo'] = $_POST['orderNo'];
                    $_SESSION['customerNo'] = $_POST['customerNo'];

                    ob_clean();
                    header( "location: order_confirm_tech_step2.php" );

                } else {
                    echo "error preparing sql"
                }
            } else {
                echo "error, one or more variables are not arrays"
            }
        } else {
            echo "error, one or more variables are not available"
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code using foreach loop on $serviceTitle

```
    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO invoice (orderNo,customerNo,productName,price,quantity,amount,createDate,createTime,createBy) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    foreach ($serviceTitle as $key => $value) {
        $statement->execute(array($orderNo,$customerNo,$value,$price[$key],$quantity[$key],$amount[$key],$date,$time,$createBy));
    }
```

However it is better to use bulk insert rather than inserting each row individually.

Comment: This suffers from exactly the same problem as the OPs original code - you only prepare the statement once outside the loop and then execute multiple times in the loop

Comment: @RamRaider It would be better if you can write the code by yourself and answered the question rather then commenting and down voting the answers. However I have just gave the sample code for what has been asked for, further improvements or changes has to be done by Amranur Rahman him self.

Comment: you will see I have asked the OP a couple of questions but he has failed to respond - without knowing the structure of the data it's not really possible to answer accurately. One other thing with your code - you define a variable as a counter but ignore the `$key` defined in the loop - you could have used that rather than another variable `$i`

Comment: @RamRaider I have updated the code as per your satisfaction. Still just for information it would also be better to execute the statement just once rather than in a loop it would be much faster than in loop execution as mention in following [Sample](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/code/495371/insert-multiple-records-with-pdo-prepared-statement)

Comment: I wasn't "having a go at you" - the fact that the statement was prepared multiple times inside the loop was not the way to do it. It might indeed be quicker to do a bulk insert rather than individual queries ( though using the execute method in a loop is quick ) but that does add the extra complexity of forming the concatenated sql and thereby losing the benefit of the prepared statement